# Do volatile keyword in java creates mutex for physical memory. If not how it ensure the "write read" order

Tags: java, volatile

Do volatile keyword in java creates mutex for physical memory. If not(I did not found any resource which ensures this) how it ensure the "write read" order.

Comment: Do not understand the reason for negative voting, please suggest reason as well, so that I could make the question better.

Comment: This explains pretty well into detail: http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect to call it mutex but on some architectures like x86 it locks the bus while reading/writing the variable. Some others have just memory barrier / fence special instructions for this which ensure correct ordering of reads/writes.

Comment: @Zvtnek : Could you also suggest some reference

Answer (score -1):

Volatile variables is to indicate compiler and JVM that always read its value from main memory.

Volatile variables are used in Concurrent programming in Java. When we declare a variable volatile, every thread reads its value from main memory and don't used cached value available in every thread stack.